# Question about vector iterator in template functions

Tags: c++, templates, stl, vector, iterator

I'm trying to learn the STL library and I'm having a weird problem. This code compiles perfectly:

```
void Show(vector<int> myvec)
{
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    cout << "Vector contains:";
    for( it = myvec.begin(); it < myvec.end(); it++) 
    {
         cout << " " << *it;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

while this one gives me an error message at compile time:

```
template <class T> 
void Show2(vector<T> myvec)
{
    vector<T>::iterator it;
    cout << "Vector contains:";
    for( it = myvec.begin(); it < myvec.end(); it++)
    {
         cout << " " << *it;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

The error is:

```
$ g++ hello.cpp
hello.cpp: In function ‘void Show2(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >)’:
hello.cpp:19: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘it’
hello.cpp:21: error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
```

It seems a very simple mistake, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to put the "template" and "typename" on dependent names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-to-put-the-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)

Comment: Likely answered a lot before, but hard to search for typename/dependent names if you don't know that such terms exist

Comment: @FredOverflow that's a very nice link and I'll probably read it right now. But, like @Erik said if you don't know what is the underlying problem, you'll search for many specific terms and never for the more general problem. I did many searches for iterators, templates, vector, STL,... and found nothing I didn't even knew the keyword `typename` existed (:( yeah, I'm a noob :P). I thought it was just a stupid syntax error.

Comment: That's fine, nobody is complaining ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to say `typename vector<T>::iterator it`.

On another note, you're passing `vector`s by value. That means the entire `vector` gets copied in the function call. `void Show(vector<T> const &myvec)` and using `const_iterator` would be wiser.

Comment: If he passes a const ref, you need to also tell him to use a const_iterator.

Answer (score 22):

You need this:

```
typename vector<T>::iterator it;
```

This tells the compiler that `vector<T>::iterator` should be treated as a type, something it can't assume since `iterator` is dependent on what `T` is.

Answer (score 4):

Some compilers have problems detecting what is a member name and what is a type name, when inside templates. Try writing something like this in the first line of your template function body.

`typename vector<T>::iterator it;`

Comment: Correct, but it is not really a compiler problem. The C++ Standard mandates that the compiler treat a dependent name in a template as a member and not a type, unless *typename* is used.

Comment: It's not "some compilers". The grammar simply does not allow it. "Some compilers" can double-guess programmer by retrying with typename if parsing fails without it and thus compiling *some* incorrect cases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works using `typename vector<T>::iterator it;`
Your compiler cannot know that there is an inner class iterator.

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance the parameter, although it uses a template, is not a template, it is a fully defined class (`vector<int>`)

In the latter instance the parameter is a template on type T and thus requires typename